# How to find container depth (eg:ArrayList<String>=1,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>=2)?

Tags: java, templates, recursion

for example, in c++, I can find int=0,vector< int >=1,vector< < vector< int > >=2 by the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class Printer{
public:
    static int print(){
        return 0;
    }
};

template <typename T,typename Alloc>
class Printer<std::vector<T,Alloc> >{
public:
    static int print(){
    return 1+Printer<T>::print();
    }
};

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",Printer<int>::print());
    printf("%d\n",Printer<std::vector<int> >::print());
    printf("%d\n",Printer<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >::print());
    return 0;
}
```

which doesn't require any instance, for example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

to do that. How can I implement this function in Java? I tried:

```
public static void print(List<Integer> list){
}

public static <T> void print(List<? extends T> list) {
}
```

and

```
public static <T>void print(){
}

public static void print() {
}
```

but both says "both methods have same erasure". I also considered using if else like:

```
public static void print(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof List){
        List list=(List)obj;
        for(Object obj2 : list){
            print(obj2);
        }
    }else{
    }
}
```

but I cannot get the type of element in the function. Is it possible to do this in Java?

Comment: A lot of examples, but to me it would be more helpful if you would be showing the actual Java lists, and what you expect to happen with them. And no, java generics are much less powerful than C++ templates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive method that will do what you're trying to achieve. Always pass 0 for the `depth` parameter on the initial call, that's the counter.

```
public static int listDepth(Object obj, int depth){
    if(obj instanceof List){                       //Check if given object is a list
        List<?> list = (List)obj;                  //Retrieve the list
        depth++;                                   //Increment depth counter
        if(list.isEmpty())                         //Nothing in the current list
            return depth;                          //Then return current depth
        else depth = listDepth(list.get(0), depth);//Else call the method on the first element, with the current depth            
    }        
    return depth;                                  //obj is not a List, we return the depth
}
```

And here's an example :

```
ArrayList second = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList first = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

first.add(second);

System.out.println(" Depth : " + listDepth(first, 0));// Output : 2
```

And an other one :

```
 ArrayList third = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList second = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
 ArrayList first = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

 third.add("Not an array");
 second.add(third);
 first.add(second);

 System.out.println(" Depth : " + listDepth(first, 0));// Output : 3
```

**EDIT :** Replaced the try/catch with a check on wether or not the list is empty, as it is a more proper way to do it.

Comment: "Always pass 0 for the depth parameter on the initial call" This is bad design. Have a private function which takes 2 parameters, and a public function which takes 1 parameter and does nothing except call `privateFunc(list, 0)`

Comment: @Michael He also can pass a variable if he wants the counter to start at a specific `int`.. I am just here to propose an algorithm that do the task, it's up to him to implement it the good way. But I get your point.

Comment: Another thing I dislike is catching the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. There's no reason you can't check the size before you call `get(0)`.

Comment: @Michael I get what you're trying to say, and you're right, in a certain way. As I said, I just provided the algorithm, the actual implementation of it is not up to me. If I had to implement it in a program, I will follow your advice.

Comment: @Michael This is true. I just prefered to put that "just in case".

Answer (score -1):

In Java，"T" will be erased in compiling.
If you wang to get depth of List , you need to ensure this List is not null. Than get the first one and check that Class.

```
public int getDepth(Object collection){
    return getDepth(collection,1);
}

/**
 * get Collection depth
 * @param depth now depth
 * @return
 */
private int getDepth(Object collection,int depth){
    Object temp;
    if(collection instanceof Collection
            && !((Collection)collection).isEmpty()){
        //get first one
        temp =  ((Collection)collection).iterator().next();
        return getDepth(temp,depth +1 );
    }else {
        return depth;
    }
}
```

:)